# Geokit-Rails: polymorphic location query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, polymorphism, geokit

Location has :lat and :lng for use with 'geokit-rails'  I'm running Rails 4.

Is it possible to do a query for distinct Collections that have Tracks in a specified Location range?

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :locatable, polymorphic: true
  acts_as_mappable
end

class Tracks < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :location, as: :locatable
belongs_to :collection
end

class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tracks
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To use polymorphic with grokit-rails you have to add acts_as_mappable through: :location to your Tracks model:

```
class Tracks < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :location, as: :locatable
  acts_as_mappable through: :location
  belongs_to :collection
end
```

And the query must be:

```
@collection.tracks.joins(:location).within(distance, :origin => @origin)
```